# I'm trying to count the number of lines in my file but my counter prints out 0 every time

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void get_input (ifstream& ifile){

    std::string filename;
    cout << "Input filename:";
    cin >> filename;

    if (ifile.fail()){
        cout << "File is not found"<< endl;
    }

    int ID, score, count = 0;

    while (1){
        ifile >> ID >> score;
        if (ifile.eof()) break;
        ++count;
    }


    ifile.close();

    cout << ID << endl;
    cout << count << endl;
    cout << score << endl;


}
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    ifstream file;

    get_input (file);

    return 0;
}
```

I changed it to std::string, but the counter still prints out 0. I am taking int data from a file that has 2 columns. I also need to count the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Use a `std::string` to receive your filename.

Comment: You are not actually opening the file.

Comment: I suggest reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on how to ask a good question. "Isn't working" is not a clear problem statement that tells us what is wrong or will be useful to people in the future.

Comment: Get things to compile is a good start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 2):

You have more than one problem.
As someone else mentioned, you're not actually opening any file.

```
if (ifile.fail()) <<this is failing & does not get entered
```

Instead try

```
if (!ifile.is_open())
```

And it will show that you're not opening anything.
Once you open the file like so;

```
ifile.open(filename);
```

Your code should work, however I can't see where you're checking for line returns. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to follow up. Try searching for std::getline.